# how to change font of textfield after click on a bold button

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextfield

I have a problem in setting font of textfield. i have made a bold button. After click on bold button, whole textfield string font set to bold. But i want only those words getting bold which typed after pressing bold button.

[image]

Comment: you should use `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: NSAttributedString *strAttributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:<add your string which have entered after clicking bold button> attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor darkGrayColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0f]}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSAttributedString` inside your `UITextView`. You have to remember the `NSRange` of bold,unbold texts for further editing. All the method you need you can find here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/